# How to define RewriteRule to skip parameter in uri

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I heve the following rule:

`RewriteRule ^/shop$ https://www.example.com/category`

the rule is working as expected with one exception:
if in url there are parameter following the shop path, for example:

https://www.example.com/shop?order=name+asc. 
I would not match this uri, but with the above sintax the rule is triggered. how can I skip it?

Comment: Note that without any _flags_ the above RewriteRule directive will result in a 302 temporary redirect and processing will continue through the file. Ideally you should be explicit about the redirect and include the R flag and use the L flag to prevent further processing.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a condition to ensure that the query string is blank:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^$"
RewriteRule ^/shop$ https://www.example.com/category
```

By default the query string is not considered by rewrite rules.  They only match the URL path.   You have to add conditions if you need to pay attention to the query string.